# How to remove SelectionLinks extension from Chrome on Windows?

Tags: uninstall, malware, malware-removal

It's not possible to remove it using the standard extension disablement/removal features in Chrome - the checkbox is disabled.

I also found that the extension gets installed under 
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\ - tried to delete it there, but it's still active. In fact, I tried deleting the whole C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\ directory, but the next time Chrome starts, it recreates it and the extension gets recreated.

Seems like there is something running in Windows that keeps detecting that Chrome extension is not there anymore and reinstates it.

Any ideas how to get rid of it?

Comment: Please, no need to provide instructions to install some software to remove this. It rarely helps, plus the trustworthiness of such software is always questionable. Manual instructions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove automatically then use Anti-Malware like softwares, if you want to do manually then follow these instructions,

**Removal Instructions:**

**Installed Software List:**

You can try to uninstall products with the names listed below; for items identified by other properties or to avoid malware getting active again on uninstallation, use Spybot-S&D or RunAlyzer to locate and get rid of these entries.

```
Products that have a key or property named "sl-adk".
```

**Files:**

Please use Windows Explorer or another file manager of your choice to locate and delete these files.

```
The file at "<$PROGRAMFILES>\OApps\bho.dll".
The file at "<$PROGRAMFILES>\OApps\ChromeAddon.pem".
The file at "<$PROGRAMFILES>\OApps\chromeaddon\._included.js".
The file at "<$PROGRAMFILES>\OApps\chromeaddon\background.html".
The file at "<$PROGRAMFILES>\OApps\chromeaddon\included.js".
The file at "<$PROGRAMFILES>\OApps\chromeaddon\manifest.json".
The file at "<$PROGRAMFILES>\OApps\dler.exe".
The file at "<$PROGRAMFILES>\OApps\sl-adk_uninstall.exe".
The file at "<$PROGRAMFILES>\OApps\status.txt".
The file at "<$PROGRAMFILES>\OApps\status2.txt".
```

Make sure you set your file manager to display hidden and system files. If SelectionLinks uses rootkit technologies, use our RootAlyzer or our Total Commander anti-rootkit plugins.
You will have to use a global search for files without a name specified. Be extra careful, because just the name might not be enough to identify files!

**Folders:**

Please use Windows Explorer or another file manager of your choice to locate and delete these folders.

```
The directory at "<$PROGRAMFILES>\OApps\chromeaddon".
The directory at "<$PROGRAMFILES>\OApps".
```

Make sure you set your file manager to display hidden and system files. If SelectionLinks uses rootkit technologies, use our RootAlyzer or our Total Commander anti-rootkit plugins.
You will have to use a global search for files without a name specified. Be extra careful, because just the name might not be enough to identify folders!

**Registry:**

You can use regedit.exe (included in Windows) to locate and delete these registry entries.

```
Delete the registry key "{517E0D3E-17A4-4592-926E-A082DB43B7D3}" at "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\".
Delete the registry key "{517E0D3E-17A4-4592-926E-A082DB43B7D3}" at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Low Rights\ElevationPolicy\".
Delete the registry key "kincjchfokkeneeofpeefomkikfkiedl" at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\Extensions\".
Delete the registry key "kincjchfokkeneeofpeefomkikfkiedl" at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Google\Chrome\Extensions\".
Delete the registry key "SelectionLinks" at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Object\".
Delete the registry value "AppName" at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Low Rights\ElevationPolicy\{517E0D3E-17A4-4592-926E-A082DB43B7D3}\".
Delete the registry value "AppPath" at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Low Rights\ElevationPolicy\{517E0D3E-17A4-4592-926E-A082DB43B7D3}\".
Delete the registry value "bhoguid" at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Object\SelectionLinks\".
Delete the registry value "DisplayName" at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\sl-adk\".
Delete the registry value "DisplayVersion" at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\sl-adk\".
Delete the registry value "installdate" at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Object\SelectionLinks\".
Delete the registry value "installid" at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Object\SelectionLinks\".
Delete the registry value "partner" at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Object\SelectionLinks\".
Delete the registry value "Policy" at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Low Rights\ElevationPolicy\{517E0D3E-17A4-4592-926E-A082DB43B7D3}\".
Delete the registry value "product" at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Object\SelectionLinks\".
Delete the registry value "Publisher" at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\sl-adk\".
Delete the registry value "UninstallString" at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\sl-adk\".
Delete the registry value "version" at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Object\SelectionLinks\".
```

I hope this will help if you want to remove manually.

Comment: I don't have the "OApps" folder under "C:\Program Files". I did find a bunch of registry entries related to SelectionLinks and I deleted them. After reboot the problem persists - SelectionLinks extension gets re-added on every start of Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware](http://www.malwarebytes.org) or [Spybot S&D](http://www.safer-networking.org), or if you're comfortable editing the registry, follow the detailed manual removal guide [here](http://forums.spybot.info/showthread.php?t=67079).

Not entirely sure what all it does besides ad-injection, but just to be safe I'd advise you to immediately change all online passwords and take steps to protect other confidential data you might have entered/accessed using the browser while infected.

Comment: Also see [How do I get rid of malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

Answer (score 0):

SelectionLinks extension can be removed using free Avast Browser Cleanup utility. It is free:

http://files.avast.com/files/tools/avast-browser-cleanup.exe

You can also use AdwCleaner to clean leftover reg keys and folders.

If **SelectionLinks** reappearing you can use Malwarebytes AntiMalware.